# Survival function - interpolation in R

Tags: r, plot, interpolation, survival

I have constructed a survival function such as:

```
  [![plot(survfit(Surv(inf.time,infection)~1),xlab="Time (days)",ylab="Survival Probability",
                        main="Time Until Staphylococcus Infection",
                        conf.int = F)][1]][1]
```

[image]

Now i would like to determine by which time has 40% of the patients had an infection? **How can this be written in R?** Either as a command that gives me a numerical value as result or directly plotted into the survival function graph.

I am aware that the survival function depicts the probability of not having an infection, therefore i can read from the graph that survival probability of 0.6 corresponds to ca. 45 days? How can i plot this into the graph?

i tried (with no luck):

```
inf.time[which(survfit(Surv(inf.time,infection)~1) == 0.6)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, you are using `survival` package, right?
So you can get data frame of all points of the survival curve from `"survfit"` object or, easily, from `"summary.survfit` because it is `list` type under the hood.
Then you can filter the df by survival  probability.
Some example:

```
library(survival)

s <- Surv(lung$time, lung$status)

sfit <- survfit(s~1)  #get usual "survfit" object

summary_sfit = summary(sfit)

surv_df = data.frame(summary_sfit[2:6])  #somehow coerce it to data.frame

head(surv_df)

##    time n.risk n.event n.censor      surv
##  1    5    228       1        0 0.9956140
##  2   11    227       3        0 0.9824561


surv_df[max(which(surv_df$surv > 0.60)), ] 
##     time n.risk n.event n.censor      surv
##  68  245    117       1        2 0.6018576
```

Or you can just subset `survfit$time` without creating data frame

```
sfit$time[max(which(sfit$surv > 0.6))]

## [1] 245
```